# How to save intensity value in sensor_msgs/Image from PointCloud?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

I am using ROS-Kinetic. I have a pointcloud of type PointCloud. I have projected the same pointcloud on a plane. I would like to convert the planar pointcloud to an image of type sensor_msgs/Image.

```
toROSMsg(cloud, image);
```

enter code hereis throwing an error as

```
error: ‘const struct pcl::PointXYZI’ has no member named ‘rgb’
         memcpy (pixel, &cloud (x, y).rgb, 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Kindly enlighten me in this regard. If possible along with a code snippet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your objective might not be that trivial. Maybe you tell us what you want to achieve with your approach, because there might be an easier way.

Comment: I would like to project velodyne pointcloud onto a plane and convert it to image. I have achieved projection. I just have to convert it to image.

Answer (score 1):

If toROSMsg() is complaining that your input cloud does not have an 'rgb' member, try to input a cloud of type pcl::PointXYZRGB. This is another type of point cloud handled by PCL. You can look at the [documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php) of PCL point types.

Convert to type pcl::PointXYZRGB with these lines:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudrgb (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::copyPointCloud(*cloud, *cloudrgb);
```

Then call your function as:

```
toROSMsg(cloudrgb, image);
```

Comment: PointCloud is of type sensor_msgs/PointCloud2, which I have converted to PointCloud<PointXYZI>. The data is taken from Velodyne. Thus, it will not have RGB values but only intensity.

Comment: Yes, but you can convert between point clouds of type <PointXYZI> and <PointXYZRGB> via the code I provided above, where *cloud is your <PointXYZI> type cloud.

Comment: If you want to view an image of the point cloud, you can also use the PCL visualizer class. Maybe take a screenshot of the visualizer while viewing your cloud. http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php#pcl-visualizer

Comment: The requirement is to pass the image to next module as ROS message.

Comment: In that case, have you referenced this tutorial?: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage Like I said in the first post, just make sure that the cloud you are using in the toROSMsg() function has been converted to a point cloud of type PointXYZRGB

Comment: Yes. I went through the same documentation. I  converted PointXYZI to PointXYZRGB and passed to the function copyPointCloud(). Problem is solved. I thank all the concerned for the immense support.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is some 2D voxelization. And I assume that you want to implement some "inverse sensor model" (ISM) as explained by [Thrun](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/), right?
This approach is commonly directly implemented into a mapping algorithm to circumvent the exhaustive calculation of the plain ISM.
Therefore, you'll hardly find an out of the box solution.

Anyway, you could do it in multiple ways like this:

1. Use [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) for 2D projection (but you have it anyway)
2. Use the ISM alg. explained in the [book](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/)

or

1. Transform the [PCL to an octree](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/group__octree.html)
2. Downsample to a quadtree and convert it to an imge

Comment: Would be nice if you could point out in which way the answer was helpful. Also, if it was helpful and correct, please mark the answer correspondingly.